# How can i overcome the KeyError: in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-analysis

I wanted to analyze the CSV datafile with the help of python. but an error occured saying KeyError:Niveau. "Niveau" was the name of the column that i had in the CSV data.

i had a CSV file and i wanted to analyze this with python. I wrote a code and the problem seemed to be KeyError:Niveau. A column was named Niveau in my CSV file. Now how to deal with the error and let the code flow. The code goes like this: and I tried by renaming the column name in the csv file and also in the code either way it  did not worked. I also tried the Row1.get['Niveau'] function but this did not worked as well. The error looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
file_path = r"C:\Users\Roman\OneDrive\Desktop\Finaltest.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

# Function to combine questions based on conditions
def combine_questions(row1, row2):
    condition1 = row1.get['Niveau'] == '5 pt Likert' and row1['Datentyp'] == 'integer'
    condition2 = row2.get['Niveau'] == 'Metrisch' and row2['Datentyp'] == 'integer'
    

    if condition1 and condition2:
        return 'Test_LiMe'
    else:
        return None

# Create a new column 'Result' by combining questions
df['Result'] = None  # Initialize the Result column

# Iterate through all combinations of questions and apply the combination function
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(df)):
        result = combine_questions(df.iloc[i], df.iloc[j])
        if result:
            df.at[i, 'Result'] = result
            df.at[j, 'Result'] = result

# Print the DataFrame to verify the results
print(df)
```

```
runfile('C:/Users/Roman/Downloads/comm-master/comm-master/comm/ZTG_data.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3629, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'Niveau'`
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the whole error traceback?  It should start with a line of code from your script, but it doesn't.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to invoke the get method improperly. Your .get should use parentheses, not square brackets. Please see [the documentation for df.get()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.get.html) to read more about it.